# angular2 - set height of components using flexbox

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

Assuming my "main" app.component.html has only three lines of code in there:

```
<app-header-component></app-header-component>
<app-content-component></app-content-component>
<app-footer-component></app-footer-component>
```

where I want header component to occupy approximately 10% of the screen, for content to have 70% and for the footer - 20%, using the flexbox layout, and this size should not be changing how much of content is in respective components.
I tried adding flexbox myself but the ratio changes, especially for the `<app-content-component>`. I believe that the issue is that `<app-content-component>` has multiple nested components inside and that is why the ratio I need does not stay the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to set up something like that is to use `flex-grow`/`flex-shrink`, where they get *n* part of the available space, here set to full viewport height.

`flex-basis` is set to `0` so the content doesn't affect how the space is distributed between items.

It will keep the 10%/70%/20% ratio for the items but both *header*/*footer* can still adjust in height if they need to, which kind of is the purpose using Flexbox.

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
my-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

app-header-component {
  flex: 1 1 0;                   /*  1 part(s) of 10  */
  background: lightblue;
}
app-content-component {
  flex: 7 7 0;                   /*  7 part(s) of 10  */
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: auto;
}
app-footer-component {
  flex: 2 2 0;                   /*  2 part(s) of 10  */
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<my-container>
  <app-header-component>
    Header
  </app-header-component>
  <app-content-component>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
    Content with many lines<br>
  </app-content-component>
  <app-footer-component>
    Footer
  </app-footer-component>
</my-container>
```

---

Note, the `10` in i.e. `/*  7 part(s) of 10  */` is the sum of each set `flex-grow`/`flex-shrink`.

Answer (score 0):

What's your css for these components? Are you explicitly setting flex-grow and flex-shrink? If using shorthand flex, I would use:

```
flex: 0 0 10%;
```

Also, set parent container (body maybe in your case, or app root) to stretch to 100% height:

```
app-root {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```